# How do if/elif/else statements work, mine doesn't run

Tags: python, if-statement

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

for x in months:

```
if x == "January":
    D = 1
    M = 11
    C = 20
    Y = 20
    month_1d_January = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
    w0_January = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
    n = 0
    while (D <= 31):
        
        W_January = (D + (2.6*M - 0.2) - 2*C + Y + (Y/4) + (C/4)) % 7
        
        w_January = math.floor(W_January)
        w0_January[n] = w_January

        month_1d_January[w0_January[0]] = D
        if w_January == 2:
            day = "Sunday"
        elif w_January == 3:
            day = "Monday"
        elif w_January == 4:
            day = "Tuesday"
        elif w_January == 5:
            day = "Wednesday"
        elif w_January == 6:
            day = "Thursday"
        elif w_January == 0:
            day = "Friday"
        elif w_January == 1:
            day = "Saturday"

        D = D + 1
        n = n + 1
        w0_January[0] = w0_January[0] + 1

month_January_pre = np.reshape(month_1d_January,(6,7)) 
month_January = np.roll(month_January_pre,-2)       


elif x == "February":
    D = 1
    M = 12
    C = 20
    Y = 20
    month_1d_February = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
    w0_February = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
    n = 0
    while (D <= 28):
        
        W_February = (D + (2.6*M - 0.2) - 2*C + Y + (Y/4) + (C/4)) % 7
        
        w_February = math.floor(W_February)
        w0_February[n] = w_February

        month_1d_February[w0_February[0]] = D
        if w_February == 2:
            day = "Sunday"
        elif w_February == 3:
            day = "Monday"
        elif w_February == 4:
            day = "Tuesday"
        elif w_February == 5:
            day = "Wednesday"
        elif w_February == 6:
            day = "Thursday"
        elif w_February == 0:
            day = "Friday"
        elif w_February == 1:
            day = "Saturday"

        D = D + 1
        n = n + 1
        w0_February[0] = w0_February[0] + 1

month_February_pre = np.reshape(month_1d_February,(6,7)) 
month_February = np.roll(month_February_pre,5)
```

This is in VSCode in Python 3.9.1. My error is for the elif x == "February", it says Expected expression pylance. There is more code after that I can post if needed, but it is pretty much the same. I think the part that is broke is the elif statement because that is what has an error, but it could be the while loop or the if statement inside the while loop. I'm used to MatLab where there is an end line for each loop/statement which helps me alot.

Comment: You can't have a dedented block between the `if:` and the `elif:` -- the `elif:` must come _immediately after_ the `if:` block.

Comment: Also, when asking questions here, please try to build a [mre] -- the *shortest possible* code that produces the problem you want help with when run without changes. There's quite a lot of code here that isn't essential to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a bad indentation. In python you don't have any symbol for ending loop or `if` statements. You need to keep constant indentation to let python know that code belongs to one block.

This fragment of code has no indentation so it is outside `if` statement. In such case `if` statement is finished and it has some code after it, so you cannot make `elif` statement, because it can appear only right after `if` statement

```
month_January_pre = np.reshape(month_1d_January,(6,7)) 
month_January = np.roll(month_January_pre,-2)
```

You can find more information here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/

This should work

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

for x in months:
    if x == "January":
        D = 1
        M = 11
        C = 20
        Y = 20
        month_1d_January = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
        w0_January = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
        n = 0
        while (D <= 31):

            W_January = (D + (2.6 * M - 0.2) - 2 * C + Y + (Y / 4) + (C / 4)) % 7

            w_January = math.floor(W_January)
            w0_January[n] = w_January

            month_1d_January[w0_January[0]] = D
            if w_January == 2:
                day = "Sunday"
            elif w_January == 3:
                day = "Monday"
            elif w_January == 4:
                day = "Tuesday"
            elif w_January == 5:
                day = "Wednesday"
            elif w_January == 6:
                day = "Thursday"
            elif w_January == 0:
                day = "Friday"
            elif w_January == 1:
                day = "Saturday"

            D = D + 1
            n = n + 1
            w0_January[0] = w0_January[0] + 1

        month_January_pre = np.reshape(month_1d_January, (6, 7))
        month_January = np.roll(month_January_pre, -2)

    elif x == "February":
        D = 1
        M = 12
        C = 20
        Y = 20
        month_1d_February = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
        w0_February = np.zeros([42], dtype=int)
        n = 0
        while (D <= 28):

            W_February = (D + (2.6 * M - 0.2) - 2 * C + Y + (Y / 4) + (C / 4)) % 7

            w_February = math.floor(W_February)
            w0_February[n] = w_February

            month_1d_February[w0_February[0]] = D
            if w_February == 2:
                day = "Sunday"
            elif w_February == 3:
                day = "Monday"
            elif w_February == 4:
                day = "Tuesday"
            elif w_February == 5:
                day = "Wednesday"
            elif w_February == 6:
                day = "Thursday"
            elif w_February == 0:
                day = "Friday"
            elif w_February == 1:
                day = "Saturday"

            D = D + 1
            n = n + 1
            w0_February[0] = w0_February[0] + 1

        month_February_pre = np.reshape(month_1d_February, (6, 7))
        month_February = np.roll(month_February_pre, 5)
```